# Why won't this trace connect to the copper pour?

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, altium

Why is Altium not letting the trace touch the copper pour?

They are both the same net.
[image]

Answer (score 12):

Right-click on your pour.  Brings up the 'properties'

Go to 'net options'

Change the pour option to 'Pour over all same net objects'

Reply if that doesn't work